# How to go to the end of an array

Tags: python, arrays

To go the the last value in an array, would you use the code:

```
j = x[len(x)-1]
```

because this seems to be giving me the last but one, so this is really a question of how the len() thing works with arrays.

Comment: You'd better use `j = x[-1]` to get the last value in a list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indexes start from 0.

```
l = [3, 5, 7]
#    0  1  2
```

The last item is at index `len(l) - 1`, not `len(l)`.

Also, use

```
j = x[-1]
```

since negative indexes count from the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use `len()` in this case. Python allows you to select by index and given that your first element in a list will always be 0, then -1 will go back to the last element of the list. In other words

```
j = x[-1]
```

Will give you the last element from a list.

Answer (score 2):

Python is zero based indexing which means array or list in python are start with zero indexing.

example:

```
>>> List = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> List[0]
'a'
>>> List[1]
'b'
```

Lets find out the length of the list `List` which means how many element inside the list, so the answer is 5, which is true. But when you want to access the last element in the list, you need to remember about `zero based indexing`. So, the index of last element will always less than the total length by 1 value.

```
>>> len(List) 
5
>>> List[len(List)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range


>>> List[len(List) -1 ]
'e'
>>>
```

Ok that is accessing the last element using the last index, but in python list, you can always accessing the last element without even knowing the length: `by using negative indexing` which start from `-1 to length of the list`

```
>>> List[-1]
'e'
>>> List[-2]
'd'
>>> List[-len(List)]
'a'  
>>>
```

So, while using the negative index, the first element will be equal to -1 to the negative value of the length of the list, because, backward indexing start from -1.

```
List:     a   b  c  d  e 
Forward:  0   1  2  3  4
Backward -5  -4 -3 -2 -1
```